# Cannot clone a git repository from local server

Tags: git

I configured a local windows server to store my git repositories, I added the HTTP protocol with IIS to be able to work with the repositories with the HTTP url, now I'm able to open the url in my browser but I can not clone-pull-push I'm getting this error message:

```
fatal: repository 'http://serverName/Git/test-repos.git/' not found
```

I gave read and write access to the folder to IIS_USRS group, I don't know if I need to add some another user?

Comment: When debugging, try to go to the lowest level possible. Since this is an HTTP server, can you do a GET request from your browser to the expected URL?